# send an array variable to formtype in symfony from the controller

Tags: sql, symfony, twig

I have an sql request in my controller:

```
    $results = $conn->query( " select field 1....fieldn from tableA " );
    $row =  $results->fetch();
```

I want to show the returned result $row in twig as dropdown menu list

in other word, how I can send the $row variable to the formtype to use it after that as choice field.

Comment: Use a choice field type and provide your $row variable as the choicelist

Answer (score 0):

Try it from the other site. Create a "Form Type" and in your "Form Type" you can use an entity field and select data from your database through doctrine for example:

```
->add('User', 'entity', array(
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'Test\TestBundle\Entity\User',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.id > 150 and u.id < 160');
    }
))
```

Then you should get an dropdown by default.

The class is here your entity class witch is automatically given to the query builder under that class field and you can use it.